MoveIt 2 Source Build issues
Newly installed OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
ROS Rolling (https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html)
Also installed:
sudo apt-get install ros-rolling-ros2-control
sudo apt-get install ros-rolling-ros2-controllers
MoveIt 2 Source Build issue (https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/):
--- stderr: moveit_msgs
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findobject_recognition_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
  this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
  by "object_recognition_msgs", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "object_recognition_msgs" with any of the following names:

    object_recognition_msgsConfig.cmake
    object_recognition_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "object_recognition_msgs" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "object_recognition_msgs_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "object_recognition_msgs" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


Entering command rosdep install -r --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
I have this:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
moveit_kinematics: No definition of [rsl] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_py: No definition of [octomap_msgs] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources_fanuc_moveit_config: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_planning_interface: No definition of [ros_testing] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_hybrid_planning: No definition of [ros_testing] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_tests: No definition of [ros_testing] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_core: No definition of [urdfdom_headers] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources_panda_moveit_config: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_planners_stomp: No definition of [rsl] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_perception: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_planning: No definition of [srdfdom] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_setup_framework: No definition of [srdfdom] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_setup_core_plugins: No definition of [srdfdom] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_move_group: No definition of [ros_testing] for OS version [jammy]
chomp_motion_planner: No definition of [rsl] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_msgs: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_planners_ompl: No definition of [ompl] for OS version [jammy]
pilz_industrial_motion_planner: No definition of [ros_testing] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources: No definition of [joint_state_publisher] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_occupancy_map_monitor: No definition of [geometric_shapes] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_visualization: No definition of [object_recognition_msgs] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_servo: No definition of [launch_param_builder] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources_prbt_support: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
dual_arm_panda_moveit_config: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_configs_utils: No definition of [srdfdom] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_warehouse: No definition of [warehouse_ros] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources_prbt_moveit_config: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_ros_benchmarks: No definition of [launch_param_builder] for OS version [jammy]
moveit_resources_prbt_pg70_support: No definition of [xacro] for OS version [jammy]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully


I have no Idea what this errors mean and how to fix this issue. Would be appreciated for any help. Thanks.
